# Enviar formulario a FastAPI y mostrar respuestas

Tags: php, python, wordpress, api

estoy trabajando con WordPress y con fastAPI, he creado un plugin que muestra un formulario, al rellenar el formulario y enviarlo, este se envía a donde se encuentra mi API, esta api procesa las respuestas del formulario y retorna resultados. Mi duda es que al enviar el formulario me muestra los resultados en mi fastAPI, pero lo que yo quiero es que se envié el formulario y me muestre los resultados en la propia página de WordPress (es decir, al enviar el formulario, que este desaparezca y me muestre los resultados ahí). Os muestro capturas y el código que he desarrollado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi formulario creado en una página de wordpress (aquí es donde quiero que al enviar este formulario se elimine y muestre las respuestas que me devuelve mi api en vez de saltar a la propia api y que me muestre allí los datos)

El código de este formulario:

```
   <?php
     /**
      * Plugin Name: Análisis Alimenticio
   * Author: Fran Zájara Gómez
   * Version: 1.0.0
   */


    // Definimos el shortcode y la función asociada.

      add_shortcode('test_analisis_alimenticio', 'form_analisis');

      //Definimos la función

     function form_analisis()
     {

    wp_enqueue_style('css_analisisalimenticio', plugins_url('style.css', __FILE__));
    ob_start();


    ?>

    <form action="https://fastapi-eatsafe.herokuapp.com/analisis/" method="post">
    <p>Nombre y apellidos:</p>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" required><br>
    
    <p>Edad:</p>
    <input type="number" name="edad" min="5" max="120" required><br>

    <p>Peso(kilogramos):</p>
    <input type="number" name="peso" min="20" max="150" required><br>

    <p>Sexo:</p>
    <select name="sexo" required>
        <option value="Hombre">Hombre</option>
        <option value="Mujer">Mujer</option>
    </select>



    <p>Cuestión 1: ¿Sueles ingerir sustancias no alimentarias comunmente?</p>
    <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion1" value="1" required>
    <label for="si">Sí</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion1" value="0" required>
    <label for="no">No</label>

    <p>Cuestión 2: Sueles tener ardores o dolores intensos en el estomago?</p>
    <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion2" value="1" required>
    <label for="si">Sí</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion2" value="0" required>
    <label for="no">No</label>
    
    <p>Cuestión 3: ¿Sueles expulsar los alimentos una vez masticados?</p>
    <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion3" value="1" required>
    <label for="si">Sí</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion3" value="0" required>
    <label for="no">No</label>

    <p>Cuestión 4: ¿Últimamente has sufrido una pérdida de peso significativa?</p>
    <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion4" value="1" required>
    <label for="si">Sí</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion4" value="0" required>
    <label for="no">No</label>
    
    <p>Cuestión 5: ¿Sueles evitar ingerir comida debido a su sabor, textura, olor o color?</p>
    <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion5" value="1" required>
    <label for="si">Sí</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion5" value="0" required>
    <label for="no">No</label>

    <p>Cuestión 6: ¿En una escala del 1 al 10 cuanto te preocuparía aumentar un poco de peso?</p>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="10" name="cuestion6" required>

    <p>Cuestión 7: ¿Crees que tu peso actual es normal?</p>
    <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion7" value="1" required>
    <label for="si">Sí</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion7" value="0" required>
    <label for="no">No</label>

    <p>Cuestión 8: ¿En los últimos meses has realizado grandes ingestas de comida?</p>
    <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion8" value="1" required>
    <label for="si">Sí</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion8" value="0" required>
    <label for="no">No</label>

    <p>Cuestión 9: ¿Te has autoprovocado el vómito o has usado laxantes?</p>
    <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion9" value="1" required>
    <label for="si">Sí</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion9" value="0" required>
    <label for="no">No</label>

    <p>Cuestión 10: ¿Frecuentas realizar grandes ingestas de comida?</p>
    <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion10" value="1" required>
    <label for="si">Sí</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion10" value="0" required>
    <label for="no">No</label>

    <p>Cuestión 11: ¿Al comer crees que no puedes controlar la cantidad de los alimentos que ingieres?</p>
    <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion11" value="1" required>
    <label for="si">Sí</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion11" value="0" required>
    <label for="no">No</label>

    <p>Cuestión 12: ¿En una escala del 1 al 10 cuanto te preocupa tu constitución y peso corporal?</p>
    <input type="range" min="0" max="10" name="cuestion12" required>

    <p>Cuestión 13: En el caso de que realices grandes ingestas de comida, ¿cuantas veces sueles hacerlo a la semana?</p>
    <input type="radio" id = "0" name="cuestion13" value="0" required>
    <label for="0">No realizo grandes ingestas de comida</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "1-3" name="cuestion13" value="1" required>
    <label for="1-3">De 1 a 3 veces por semana</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "4-7" name="cuestion13" value="2" required>
    <label for="4-7">De 4 a 7 veces por semana</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "8-13" name="cuestion13" value="3" required>
    <label for="8-13">De 8 a 13 veces por semana</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "14" name="cuestion13" value="4" required>
    <label for="4">14 o más veces por semana</label>

    <p>Cuestión 14: En el caso de que realices grandes ingestas de comida, selecciona las con cuales de las afirmaciones siguientes estás de acuerdo:</p>
    
    <input type="checkbox" name="cuestion14a" value="1" id="check-1">
    <label for="check-1">Como muy rápido</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cuestion14b" value="1" id="check-2">
    <label for="check-2">Como aunque no tenga hambre</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cuestion14c" value="1" id="check-3">
    <label for="check-3">Al final de comer siento malestar físico</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cuestion14d" value="1" id="check-4">
    <label for="check-4">Suelo comer solo, sin que nade me acompañe</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cuestion14e" value="1" id="check-5">
    <label for="check-5">Al final de comer me siento deprimido</label><br>


    
    
    

    <p>Cuestión 15: ¿Sueles ingerir alimentos por la noche al despertarte del sueño o después de cenar?</p>
    <input type="radio" id = "si" name="cuestion15" value="1" required>
    <label for="si">Sí</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "no" name="cuestion15" value="0" required>
    <label for="no">No</label>
    
    
    <p>Cuestión 16: En el caso de que te autoprovoques el vómito o uses laxantes, ¿cuantas veces sueles hacerlo a la semana?</p>
    <input type="radio" id = "0" name="cuestion16" value="0" required>
    <label for="0">No realizo grandes ingestas de comida</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "1-3" name="cuestion16" value="1" required>
    <label for="1-3">De 1 a 3 veces por semana</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "4-7" name="cuestion16" value="2" required>
    <label for="4-7">De 4 a 7 veces por semana</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "8-13" name="cuestion16" value="3" required>
    <label for="8-13">De 8 a 13 veces por semana</label>
    <input type="radio" id = "14" name="cuestion16" value="4" required>
    <label for="4">14 o más veces por semana</label>
    

    <br>
    <p></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">

    
    
</form>

 <?php
 
// Devuelve el contenido del buffer de salid
return ob_get_clean();

 }
```

y por último dejo el código que tengo en mi api main:

```
   from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
   import json
   from pydantic import BaseModel
    from funciones import *
     from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder

    app = FastAPI()

      @app.get('/inicio')
      async def rutadeprueba():
           return "Hola desde FastAPI"

      @app.get("/mul")
       async def calc(request:Request):
             num1= int(request.form.get('num1'))
             num2= int(request.form.get('num2'))
             return num1*num2

    class Respuestas(BaseModel):
     number1: int
     number: int

     class Config:
         orm_mode = True

    @app.post('/posts')
    async def create(respuesta: Respuestas):
     return respuesta

          #return Pica(respuesta[0], respuestaj[1])

     @app.post("/analisis/")
     async def analisis(nombre: str = Form(...), 
            edad: int = Form(...), 
            peso: int = Form(...),
            sexo: str = Form(...),
            cuestion1: int = Form(...),
            cuestion2: int = Form(...),
            cuestion3: int = Form(...),
            cuestion4: int = Form(...),
            cuestion5: int = Form(...),
            cuestion7: int = Form(...),
            cuestion8: int = Form(...),
            cuestion9: int = Form(...),
            cuestion10: int = Form(...),
            cuestion11: int = Form(...),
            cuestion12: int = Form(...),
            cuestion13: int = Form(...),
            cuestion14: list = Form(...),
            cuestion15: int = Form(...),
            cuestion16: int = Form(...)):

             return cuestion14
```

El código de la api realmente no hace nada ahora mismo pero es porque primero quiero solucionar el problema que he expuesto.

Comment: Cuando obtengas tus respuestas, conviértelos en un json y retorna esa respuesta, luego en wordpress cuando haces la petición a la api simplemente debes de obtener esa respuesta, como si fuese un ajax, aunque eso depende si estas haciendo la petición con curl o JavaScript, luego a esa respuesta le puedes hacer un echo dentro de algún div para ver que respuesta retorna.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Plugin name: Insert in DB
 */

// Relalizamos el formulario en un Shortcode
function make_form()
{
    ?>
<div>
    <form id="myForm" name="myform" action="<?php echo esc_url(admin_url('admin-post.php')); ?>" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="save_my_custom_form" />
        <label for="nombre">Nombre del Post:</label>
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
        <label for="custom-field">Custom Field</label>
            <input type="text" name="custom-field" id="custom-field">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</div>
<?php
}

add_shortcode('form', 'make_form');


//Añadimos los Hooks para pasar las varaibles por post
add_action('admin_post_nopriv_save_my_custom_form', 'process_contact_form');
add_action('admin_post_save_my_custom_form', 'process_contact_form');

//Aqui es donde debe de ir tu logica para enviar a fastapi
function process_contact_form()
{
    $name = $_POST['nombre'];
    /** Insert in Custom Post Types */
    $value = $_POST['custom-field'];
    $field_name = 'yourprefix_demo_text';
    

    // Gather post data.
    $my_post = array(
        'post_title' => $name,
        'post_content' => 'This is my post.',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
    );

    // Insert the post into the database.
    $the_post_id = wp_insert_post($my_post);

    __update_post_meta($the_post_id, $field_name, $value);

    wp_redirect(home_url());
}
```